# "Non-portable path to file "File.h"; specified path differs in case from file name on disk" warning in bridging header after updating to Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I updated to Xcode 8.3 and Swift 3.1 and got this warning in my bridging header file, referencing to an Objective-C header file:

> Non-portable path to file "File.h"; specified path differs in case from file name on disk

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It turned out that I misspelled the file's name, the correct name was "FILE.h" instead of "File.h". The warning appeared because of the soon coming APFS to macOS.

Comment: But when you upgrade your file system to APFS, it *will* be case sensitive and this code will no longer compile.

Comment: Thanks, I will include this in my answer.

Comment: I'm getting a bunch of these warnings and they're all false. Why would it flag the problem when it doesn't exist?

Comment: me too! damn capital letters

Comment: Thanks. Renamed the file according to the class name and the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the  **!!project folder name!!**  isn't match the bridging header path.

I changed

"**project**/project-Bridging-Header.h"

to

"**Project**/project-Bridging-Header.h"

**Tested on Xcode 9.3**

Answer (score 2):

One additional cause, that I experienced, was that a library project was importing itself incorrectly. For example, given projects **Main** and **Library**, Main would import Library with:

```
#import "Library/Library.h"
```

If Library attempts to use the same import, the *Non-portable path* warning will appear. Removing the path portion is the easy fix:

```
#import "Library.h"
```

The better fix is to import the specific components that Library needs from itself:

```
#import "Widget.h"
#import "NSString+Library.h"
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the problem in Qt (C++) on a MacOS computer from a code developed and working on Ubuntu.

My project had two files : `server.cpp` and `Server.cpp`.

The solution was to change the name of one file or the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the file names because it's a library code you could make the files that include your libraries case-sensitive! (If your PC is Windows 10 or up)

1. Open Powershell(Admin)
2. Use `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` too enable case-sensitivity atribute
3. Restart the PC
4. Use`fsutil.exe file SetCaseSensitiveInfo YourDestinationFolder enable` to enable case-sentivity

This could make the file case sensitive and solve the build problem.