# Incorrect warning from Xcode 8.3.2: Non-portable path to file - specified path differs in case from file name on disk

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, compiler-warnings

For some reason my code base suddenly started getting THOUSANDS of these warnings. But so far all the files & paths in question are exactly correct, matching what I see on disk with Finder. Are they secretly some other case under the covers? Why the heck would Xcode generate these warnings when the problem doesn't actually exist?

Although http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067017/non-portable-path-to-file-file-h-specified-path-differs-in-case-from-file-na is about the same warning, in this case **I've verified that the import paths match the filenames on disk**.

Comment: Same here (not thousand, but dozens).

Comment: I think that this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43067018/718925.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Non-portable path to file "File.h"; specified path differs in case from file name on disk" warning in bridging header after updating to Xcode 8.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067017/non-portable-path-to-file-file-h-specified-path-differs-in-case-from-file-na)

Comment: I read that one. This is different.

Comment: In what is it different? Have you checked folders' names?

Comment: Yes, I've verified the names it's complaining about are correct in Finder. Also, the same code compiles fine on Linux which is case-sensitive.

Comment: same here, if i "correct" the name it fails

Answer (score 3):

My error was this: 
**non-portable path to file gpuimagedirectionalsobeledgedetectionfilter.h specified path differs in case from file name on disk**

GPUimageDirectionalSobelEdgeDetectionFilter.h

What I did here, I located the GPUimageDirectionalSobelEdgeDetectionFilter.h
file that's causing this error and copied the name as it was in the folder and pasted it into the code. Worked.

so I removed `#import GPUimageDirectionalSobelEdgeDetectionFilter.h` and added the same line with the pasted .h name. This solved the problem.

Used Xcode 8.3.2

Answer (score 1):

You will get this warning if include/import statement has the wrong case for
a header file. If you have file with name XYZ.h you should import "XYZ.h" (same case).